# Constraints are not working?

Tags: java, jquery, regex, constraints

Hi i have two constraints one for address and another one for comments.
for address i want to include only small and capital letters,digits, white space,hypon,'.,and comma and for this i write these regex patteren.
for client side : `final String regexp = "/^[a-zA-Z\\d\\s-',.]+$/";`
for server side:  `final Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "([a-zA-Z\\d\\s-',.])+");`

for comment constraint i want to allow every character except `^<>%*()#!?`
and for this my regex patteren is for client side:

```
final String regexp = "/[^<>%*()#!?]+$/";
```

for server side :

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/[^<>%*()#!?]+$/");
```

But it is not working properly address is not taking any space anyone can help

Answer (score 2):

Server side regex should be

```
[a-zA-Z\\d\\s\\-',.]+
```

`-` is used to specify range. If you want to use only `-` in string take it as `\\-`

Comment: There're no needs to escape the dot in a character class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the dash in the character class. Without, a range is taken from `space` to `single quote` (ie: ascii 32 to ascii 39).

```
[a-zA-Z\\d\\s\\-',.]
```

You could also put the dash at the begining or at the end of the character class:

```
[a-zA-Z\\d\\s',.-]
```

or

```
[-a-zA-Z\\d\\s',.]
```

Updated according to comment: *i want to allow every character except <>%*()#!?*

```
[^<>%*()#!?]
```

You don't need anchors nor modifier if you want to test if it exists at least one invalid character in the string.

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/[^<>%*()#!?]/");
```

Comment: and what will be the regex patteren for this - i want to allow every character except ^<>%*()#!?

Comment: in my pattern i was using ^[^<>%*()#!?]+$ i.e "+" before doller is this is the reason for the error ??